# Parsing date string and retrieving day with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've had a look through some of the suggestions in similar answers here but I can't find much that helps me.

Say I have a string that contains a date and a number: 2014-06-24 00:00:00

How would I parse it in a way that I can return this: 2014-06-24 00:00:00 Tuesday

Using date.parse as such:

```
new Date(Date.parse('2014-06-24 00:00:00'))
```

gives me the following result:

Tue Jun 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

js

//var a = new Date();

```
var a = new Date(Date.parse('2014-06-24 00:00:00'))

var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

year = a.getFullYear()
month = a.getMonth()
date = a.getDate()
hour = a.getHours()
minutes = a.getMinutes()
seconds = a.getSeconds()
day = a.getDay()

alert(year + "-" + month+ "-" + date + "  " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "  " +  days[a.getDay()])

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = year + "-" + month+ "-" + date + "  " + hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "  " +  days[a.getDay()]
```

you can check the demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/7ohh7mjv/

Answer (score 1):

Use methods getDay(),getDate() etc. to extract fields and format resulting string.

There are several JS sprintf implementations:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3932473/2053898
https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js

Answer (score 0):

http://momentjs.com is a great, powerful library for easy date manipulation. Worth using if you're doing a lot of it.  To get 2014-06-24 00:00:00 Tuesday you could do (after linking in the library, of course).

```
var m = moment("2014-06-24T00:00:00");
var output = m.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss dddd');
```

But, really, check out the docs, because this is just the tip of the iceberg:  http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/